# Redemption on Windows Server 2019 with RDS (terminal server)

Tags: outlook-addin, mapi, outlook-redemption, windows-server-2019, outlook-2019

I'm experiencing a strange issue with Redemption in a RDS setup.
When running Outlook as an ordinary user I get the following exception when attempting to connect to the session:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): Interface not supported
at Redemption.IRDOSession.set_MAPIOBJECT(Object Value)

However, when running Outlook as Administrator (but with the same Exchange mailbox) there is no error and everything works.
I have tried both with Exchange cached mode enabled and without, this does not seem to make any difference.

The C# code is like this:
...
RDOSession session = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
session.MAPIOBJECT = applicationObject.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
...

Versions:
Windows Server 2019, version 1809.
Outlook 2019 MSO (16.0.10386.20017) 64-bit.
Redemption 5.5.0.3218.

Any ideas would be welcome :)

Comment: Is this inside an Outlook addin? Or a standalone app? In the former case, is this being done on a secondary thread?

Comment: Hi Dmitry. The code is running inside an Outlook addin. I'm wondering if the ordinary user is missing some permission wrt. the mailbox, but normal Outlook usage seems to work fine.

Comment: But is your code running on the main Outlook thread or on a secondary thread?

Comment: The code runs on a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Do not access `applicationObject.Session.MAPIOBJECT` on a secondary thread in your VSTO addin. Save its value on the main thread in a dedicated variable/member field, and use that variable on the secondary thread to set `RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT` property - this way only `IMAPISession` MAPI interface is marshaled, but not the Application OOM object (which does not like it).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Setting MAPIOBJECT on the main thread did not fix the error.
However, deleting Registry key

"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PreviewHandlers\Microsoft Windows MAPI Preview Handler"

fixed it.

In my initial question I forgot to mention (sorry), that just before the Redemption exception there was a "Microsoft Office Outlook" popup saying “Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fulfill the message request”. So I guess that was causing the Remption exception, even if I still haven't figured out the root cause or why it worked when running as Administrator.